# ie7 not letting me type in textbox but yes chrome, firefox, ie8 

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I have the following .jsp (signIn.jsp):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<div id="logBanner">

<form id="regForm" class="little-form" action="../user/signIn" method="post" >  
                    <label id="lblNickname" for="txtNickname">Nombre de usuario:</label>
                    <input id="txtNickname" type="text" name="nickname"  />
                    <label id="lblPsw" for="txtPsw">Contraseña:</label>
                    <input id="txtPsw" type="password" name="password"/>
                    <p><button type="submit" id="btnIngresar" >Ingresar</button></p>
</form> 
</div>
```

When the user clicks on a button in the homepage the following javascript function is called which renders the form:

```
function displaySignForm(){

    jQuery.get('../../jsp/signIn.jsp', {}, function renderForm(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){   
     var log = document.getElementById('log');
     preDiv = document.getElementById('signInWindow');
     if (preDiv==null){
         var div = document.createElement('div');
         div.id = "signInWindow";
         div.innerHTML = data;
         log.appendChild(div);
     }
     else {
         log.removeChild(preDiv);
     }
    }
    );
}
```

Which gets the form and shows it in the web page.

My problem is the following: on ie7 I can´t neither write on the textbox nor press the submit button, it looks like if everything was disabled. It does work fine on ie8, chrome and firefox. What could it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with z-index of divs. I have faced similar issues in IE7 and used this script:

```
<!--[if IE]>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//zIndex FIX for IE 7 and 8 Starts Here

    jQuery(function() {
        var zIndexNumber = 9000;
        jQuery('div').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
            zIndexNumber -= 10;         

            var overlay = zIndexNumber * 1000;
            var overlaylevel = overlay * 10;
            jQuery('#sbox-overlay').css('zIndex', overlay);
            jQuery('#sbox-window').css('zIndex', overlay);
        });

    }); 
//zIndex FIX for IE 7 and 8 ENDS Here 
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Didn't it need an opening script tag?